# different size of the same enum type

Tags: c, enums, embedded

The sizes of enum types in the following code are different, why? Will the declararation of an enum type will cause gcc to treat it as `signed int`? And this feature cause a problem in my project, for example, the size of one enum type is 1 in "file_1.c", but the size of it is 4 in "file_2.c".

My test code:

```
enum foo foo_test(void);

enum foo {
    FOO_0
};

enum bar {
    BAR_0
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("sizeof(enum foo) %d, sizeof(enum bar) %d\n", sizeof(enum foo), sizeof(enum bar));
    return 0;
}
```

- When I compile it with arm-none-eabi-gcc v4.9.3 in my embedded project

  - the output is `sizeof(enum foo) 4, sizeof(enum bar) 1`.
- When I compile it with gcc v4.8.3 in Windows

  - compile with `gcc -Wall -o sizeofTest.exe sizeofTest.c`

    - the output is `sizeof(enum foo) 4, sizeof(enum bar) 4`.
  - compile with `gcc -Wall -fshort-enums -o sizeofTest.exe sizeofTest.c`

    - the output is `sizeof(enum foo) 4, sizeof(enum bar) 1`.

Comment: and you are using `%d`, why? you must use `%zu` for an argument type `size_t`.

Comment: On Linux with gcc 6.2 I get `4` for all sizes, both with `%d` and `%zu`

Comment: so my bet about short enums was right

Comment: On Linux with gcc 6.2.1 and -fshort-enums both prints as `1` (using %zu).

Comment: What this all boils down to is that there should never be a reason to forward declare an enum in the first place. If you don't want really weird program behavior, then don't write really weird code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As is so common with the questions asking about peculiar outcomes in [c](/questions/tagged/c), the reason here is **undefined behaviour**. The C11 standard draft n1570 [6.7.2.3p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.3p3):

> 3. A type specifier of the form
>
>    ```
>    enum identifier
>    ```
>
>    without an enumerator list **shall** only appear after the type it specifies **is complete.**

And of completeness in [C11 6.7.2.2p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2p4):

> 4. [...] The enumerated type is incomplete until immediately after the } that terminates the list of enumerator declarations, and complete thereafter.

As a *shall* in a *constraints* section was violated, a conforming compiler must output a diagnostics message - however GCC by default isn't a conforming implementation unless you ask it to be `-pedantic`:

> ```
> ISO C forbids forward references to ‘enum’ types [-Werror=pedantic]
>  enum foo foo_test(void);
>       ^
> ```

---

Now, it seems that the compiler there uses the *shortest* possible enums for any type. Since you used the `enum foo` *before* it was actually defined what was in there, the compiler had to resort to `int` for its type, otherwise `char` was used. It can be reproduced with `-fshort-enums`. Your program prints `4 1`, whereas this program prints `1 1` with `-fshort-enums` on my gcc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum foo {
    FOO_0
};

enum foo foo_test(void);    

enum bar {
    BAR_0
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("sizeof(enum foo) %zu, sizeof(enum bar) %zu\n", 
            sizeof(enum foo), sizeof(enum bar));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The issue is cause by the "forward references to ‘enum’ types [-Werror=pedantic]". Is there any other option, but not "-Werror=pedantic", can be used to detect this case?

Comment: I am using some third party open source code in my project, "-Werror=pedantic" will cause many compiling error. And the case in the third party code is described as follows:
* "file_1.h" define "enum foo".
* “file_2.h” declare "enum foo foo_test(void);"
* other c files may include "file_1.h" first, or "file_2.h" first, causing enum foo has different size in different c files. 
I don't know how many issues in this third party open source, I want to detect "forward references to ‘enum’ types" as an error, and fix the issue.

Comment: I have checked the gcc manual, but didn't find any other option to detect "forward references to ‘enum’ types".

Comment: @Ivan use `-pedantic` which would just give a warning; `-pedantic` with `-Werror` will give an error.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, fix the *undefined behaviour* in your code. The correct format specifier for the `sizeof` expression type is `%zu`.

The backing type of an enumerator in C can be `char`, `int`, or `unsigned`. The compiler can pick any of these so long as it is capable of storing all the enumerated values.

So a value of 1 is feasible (as `sizeof(char)` is always 1), and you have asked some of your compilers to squeeze the `enum` backing types.

The fact that an `int` appears to be chosen for the backing type for `foo` is due, I think, to your referring to `enum foo` before you define it, and your friendly C compiler is using some sort of implicit `int`. Such an implicit declaration is no longer standard C and your code is not strictly portable.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum

Comment: good intuition, check Antti's answer. your answer _answers_ the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is undefined behavior.

You must use `%zu` to make `printf()` format a value of type `size_t`.

If the size of the value differs from that of `int`, the code in `printf()` will mis-read the varargs-argument and get the wrong idea of its value (`va_arg(args, int);` instead of `va_arg(args, size_t);`.

Comment: it does not answer the question and for this range of numbers it actually doas not matter.

Comment: Actually it might matter. Undefined behaviour means the entire program behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 What? Do you think integers are passed using different sizes depending on the value? That's not how it works. If `size_t` is 8 bytes, but `int` is 4, printing `size_t` as `%d` will not do the right thing at all, regardless of the value being printed.

Comment: little endian + 8 bytes size_t and %d will display the correct value - but of course it is the UB. But in this case with quite predictable behaviour :)

Comment: @PeterJ_01: I've noticed on more than one occasion that you have a somewhat relaxed attitude to undefined behaviour and portability. Such an approach is become progressively more harmful as optimising compilers become more aggressive.

Comment: But doess not explain the difference in sizes. So where is the actual answer?

Comment: it is not the answer it a nitpicker comment

Comment: I use "zu" instead of "%d", the output is no difference.

Comment: @unwind it is arm-none-eabi-gcc so  `If size_t is 8 bytes,` is always `false`

Answer (score -1):

The answer is actually quite simple.

As you have function prototype returning enum type, the compiler assumes it as the int and its size is hardware dependent (in your case 4 bytes) It is done for the optimisation purposes. For the another one is stored in the smallest possible data type. (probably -Os optimisation and / or -fshort-enums were used)

For coders having the real programming experience this behaviour is well known, and that is the reason to do not declare functions as returning enums if you want to keep them short.

For C standard fanatics `uint8_t foo();` and `return FOO_0;` might be unacceptable but the programming is a real, live and practical science.

Comment: Intresting no comments

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes... revenge because criticizing high-rep below par answer? you have my UV.